# No puedo insertar contenido con caracteres especiales a base de datos

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando en importar un Excel con la librería PHPExcel con PHP en codeigniter.

Tiene caracteres como `" "`, no permitiendo la inserción a mi base de datos con Postgres. Esta es mi función dentro del modelo que inserta los registros:

```
public function excel($table_name,$sql)
    {
        //si existe la tabla
        if ($this->db->table_exists("$table_name"))
        {
            //si es un array y no está vacio
            if(!empty($sql) && is_array($sql))
            {

                //si se lleva a cabo la inserción
                if($this->db->insert_batch("$table_name",$sql))
                {
                    return TRUE;
                }else{
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
Error Number:

ERROR: syntax error at or near ""country_sir,ps_pool"" LINE 1: ...on, comentario, current_cs_pool, id_country_sir," "country_s... ^

INSERT INTO "ept" ("att_site_name, att_node_name, att_name, att_tech, att_cell_id, att_cell_id_name, node_b_m2000, name, latitud, longitud, state, id_state, country, id_country, region, market, distance_from_mex_usa_border_line_miles, range, time_zone, cell_average_heihgt, altitude_m, solution, coverage, infraestructure_type, owner, mcc, mnc, nir, propagation_model, cell_radius_m, status, frec, band_indicator, band, band_width, ul_fc_mhz, dl_fc_mhz, ul_uarfcn_earfcn, dl_uarfcn_earfcn, carrier, cellname, node_b_id, physical_sector, cell_id, local_cell_id, psc_pci, rnc, rnc_id, lac_tal, tac, rac, ura, sac, time_offset, max_transmit_power_of_cell, pcpich_rs_power, antenna_height, geographic_azimuth, magnetic_declination, magnetic_azimuth, mech_tilt, elect_tilt, antenna_count_per_sector, antenna_model, beam_width, root_sequence_idx, tx_rx, ept_date, project, batch, update_type, update_date, vendor, cluster, operador, tracker, asl_local, asl_ift, nir_ift, _911, _89, region_celular, region_pcs, municipio, id_location, location, comentario, current_cs_pool, id_country_sir," "country_sir,ps_pool") VALUES (NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp2/htdocs/rf/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente tienes que escapar el INPUT antes de enviarlo a la base de datos, no estás proporcionando mucha información de como se insertan estos datos en tu base así que te comparto varias ideas generales que puedes aplicar:

**pg_escape_string:** Esta función escapa un string haciéndolo seguro para insertar

```
$datos_seguros = pg_escape_string($texto_a_insertar);
pg_query("INSERT INTO table (name, data) VALUES ('texto inseguro', '{$datos_seguros}')");
```

---

**pg_prepare:** Prepara un query para aceptar parámetros solamente, los parámetros enviados serán escapados automáticamente. Útil cuando el query se ejecuta muchas veces.

```
pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", 'INSERT INTO table (name, data) VALUES ($1, $2)'); //Aquí preparas tu query.
while(){
  $resultado = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", [$string_sucio, $string_sin_escapar]);
}
```

---

**pg_query_params:** Prepara y ejecuta un query anónimo. Es muy útil cuando se ejecuta el query UNA sola vez

```
$resultado = pg_query_params($dbconn, 'INSERT INTO table (name, data) VALUES ($1, $2)', [$string_sucio, $string_sin_escapar]);
```

---

**REGEX**: Puedes eliminar TODO lo que no quieres insertar en tu documento, este ejemplo regresa un string alfanumérico.

```
$resultado = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $string_sucio);
```

Answer (score -1):

Tendrías que escapar los caracteres especiales.
En programación cuando escribes un String lo haces entre comillas dobles "" (Aunque no en todos los lenguajes). 
Cuando escribes una instrucción SQL en programación la escribes en un String que empieza por ", pero si parte de la instrucción que quieres escribir tiene comillas dobles en alguna parte el compilador entiende que el String se ha cerrado ahí. Para evitar este problema lo normal es escapar los caracteres especiales anteponiendo una barra inversa \ aunte ellos.

Para ello hay varias funciones que permiten escapar todos los caracteres especiales de un String como la primera propuesta que ha hecho Solrac o la que he puesto antes.

Quizás esto te sirva: http://php.net/manual/es/function.addslashes.php

Comment: Buenas amigo por favor podrías especificar un poco mejor tu respuesta para que la comunidad entienda mejor

Comment: Claro, edito la respuesta para hacerlo más claro.

Comment: En la misma documentación del link que agregaste, dice "*Para escapar parámetros de bases de datos, deberían usarse funciones de escape específicas de cada SGBD por razones de seguridad*". No es tan sencillo, y una respuesta como esta hace que sea vulnerables a inyección.